# Fourier cosine series and abel's integral operator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am reading a [research paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/44f5/81abef0699fdb14bb0c7d59c073c602ecdfb.pdf). If you look at equation $(2.7)$ in the pdf , the authors write a Fourier cosine series as an Abels integral:

> $$\begin{align}\frac{a_0}2+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\cos(n\theta)~=~\cos\frac12\theta\int_{\theta}^{\pi-\varepsilon}\frac{h_1(t)dt}{\sqrt{\cos\theta-\cos t}}\tag{2.7}\end{align}$$

Does anyone know a reference for such a representation. Where can I read more about this?

Nav